# Bootsrap Cards: scale to content to fit card-body

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I found a bootstrap template, that using css and js, can display bootsrap-cards and flip them, on hover
Css-wise, each card content is held under 2 different DIV tags and nested tags
[source](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/team-design-card-flipper-using-bootstrap-4)

I wanted to edit the back side of each card, but once I do, the backside size changes, in comparison with the front side, so when the card flips, the size of the card will remain the same

I have a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9cfgm7nj/) with the modifications so far, and the card when each side in a different size

Below is the code

HTML

```
<!-- Team -->
<section id="team" class="pb-5">
    <div class="container">
        <h5 class="section-title h1">Test</h5>
        <h6><small><a href="test">test</a></small></h6>
        <div class="row">
            <!-- Team member -->


            <!-- Team member -->
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                <div class="image-flip" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
                    <div class="mainflip">
                        <div class="frontside">
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-body text-center">
                                    <p><img class=" img-fluid" src="https://sunlimetech.com/portfolio/boot4menu/assets/imgs/team/img_03.png" alt="card image"></p>
                                    <h4 class="card-title">Sunlimetech</h4>
                                    <p class="card-text">This is basic card with image on top, title, description and button.</p>
                                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="backside">
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-body text-center mt-4">
                                      <ul class="list-group list-group-flush"> <!--  -->
                                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="https://www.google.com/" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><h6>Google</h6></a></li>
                                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="https://www.google.com/" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"><h6>Another Google</h6></a></li>
                                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="https://www.google.com/"><h6>Blah Blah Blah longer text than just "google"</h6></a></li>
                                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="https://www.google.com/"><h6>Another list Item</h6></a></li>
                                    </ul>                                    <ul class="list-inline">
                                        <li class="list-inline-item">
                                            <a class="social-icon text-xs-center" target="_blank" href="https://www.google.com/">
                                                <i class="fa fa-newspaper-o"></i>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="list-inline-item">
                                            <a class="social-icon text-xs-center" target="_blank" href="https://www.linkedin.com/">
                                                <i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="list-inline-item">
                                            <a class="social-icon text-xs-center" target="_blank" href="https://www.gmail.com/">
                                                <i class="fa fa-address-book"></i>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="list-inline-item">
                                            <a class="social-icon text-xs-center" target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/">
                                                <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li class="list-inline-item">
                                            <a class="social-icon text-xs-center" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/">
                                                <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- ./Team member -->


        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<!-- Team -->
```

CSS

```
/* FontAwesome for working BootSnippet :> */

@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');
#team {
    background: #eee !important;
}

.btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary:focus {
    background-color: #108d6f;
    border-color: #108d6f;
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: none;
}

.btn-primary {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #007b5e;
    border-color: #007b5e;
}

section {
    padding: 60px 0;
}

section .section-title {
    text-align: center;
    color: #007b5e;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#team .card {
    border: none;
    background: #ffffff;
}

.image-flip:hover .backside,
.image-flip.hover .backside {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
    border-radius: .25rem;
}

.image-flip:hover .frontside,
.image-flip.hover .frontside {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.mainflip {
    -webkit-transition: 1s;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transition: 1s;
    -moz-transition: 1s;
    -moz-transform: perspective(1000px);
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: 1s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: relative;
}

.frontside {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    z-index: 2;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.backside {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: white;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 7px 9px -4px rgb(158, 158, 158);
    -moz-box-shadow: 5px 7px 9px -4px rgb(158, 158, 158);
    box-shadow: 5px 7px 9px -4px rgb(158, 158, 158);
}

.frontside,
.backside {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: 1s;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transition: 1s;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -o-transition: 1s;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transition: 1s;
    -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: 1s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.frontside .card,
.backside .card {
    min-height: 312px;
}

.backside .card a {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #007b5e !important;
}

.frontside .card .card-title,
.backside .card .card-title {
    color: #007b5e !important;
}

.frontside .card .card-body img {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}



@import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css");
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Libre+Baskerville:400,700');
body{
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
*:hover{
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
section{
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    background: #fff;  /* fallback for old browsers */
    padding:30px 0;
}
h1{float:left; width:100%; color:#232323; margin-bottom:30px; font-size: 14px;}
h1 span{font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', serif; display:block; font-size:45px; text-transform:none; margin-bottom:20px; margin-top:30px; font-weight:700}
h1 a{color:#131313; font-weight:bold;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use matchHeight:
First, put this in footer

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.matchHeight/0.7.2/jquery.matchHeight-min.js"></script>
```

Second, put this in footer (next to code above)

```
$(".card").matchHeight();
```

Here is the demo:
https://codepen.io/Lincox/pen/RqpERa

Comment: Thanks for the answer. and if it works, don't worry about it  ;)

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to upvote and accept my answer as a right answer. Thank you.

Comment: That works ! any way I can have the card to be set with a max size, so that the content would shrink accordingly ?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your idea, but in your case above, you just simply put `width: 500px` in the class `.frontside` and `.backside` like this: `.frontside, .backside{
  width: 500px;
}` you can change the number 500px